# PHP and MySQL, the code does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to ask for help in a mini project, the project consists of updating two records of a MySQL database, I have a record that is called nom and another one that is called code, I want to enter a page html or Php (I do not care, either) and change the registry, for example, if I have a registry with the name Juan and with the code 123456, I want to be able to rename the name and the code, in The table there are only 2 columns the nom and the code.

I hope I explained correctly and thank you very much for the help.

Code1:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT code, name FROM codes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo    "<tr><td>".$row["code"]."</td>"
                "<td>".$row["name"]." </td>"
                "<td><a href='editar.php?id=".$row["code"].&.$row["name"]."'>Editar</a></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Code2:

```
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "****";

$nom = $_GET["nom"]
$_GET["code"]

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE nom, code SET WHERE name=$nom";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp. You go a problem with the update.

Comment: I think the error occurs here: `$sql = "UPDATE nom, code SET WHERE name=$nom";` have you tried `$sql = "UPDATE nom, code SET WHERE name=".$nom.";` ?

Comment: `UPDATE nom, code SET` -> set what ? any column ?

Comment: If you write variables between " ", it will count as a string.

Comment: "UPDATE nom, code SET WHERE name='$nom'"; use this. I will suggest you to use prepare statements and filter_input with proper sanitize filter. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @Jordi Garcia you have an answer below

Comment: you realize that if you go online with this or are already live, that your site/db are open to being compromised because of an possible SQL injection. If you don't want that, use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is multiple issue in your code,

```
$name = $_GET["name"];
$code = $_GET["code"]; // forget to assign it
```

Also :

```
<td><a href='editar.php?id=".$row["code"].&.$row["name"]."'>Editar</a></td></tr>;
```

The "&" will not work, you need to do it like that I think :

```
<td><a href='editar.php?code=".$row["code"]."&name=".$row["name"]."'>Editar</a></td></tr>;
```

Add `&name=` before the `$row["name"]` and use `code=` before `$row["code"]` since you use `$_GET["code"];` inside Php.

There is also a problem with the update

```
$sql = "UPDATE codes SET name = '".$name."', code = $code WHERE name= '".$nom."'";
```

Additionnal information, I did not use quotes around `$code` since `$code` looks like an integer, and so, you do not need to convert it as a string.

Btw, you should check that `$name` and `$code` are correct, cause if you use them like that, some SQL injection could be done. [Check @Twinfriends comments]

**Always** check input

Edit : As @Mubashar comments out, use for example : http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Thanks to @Masivuye for is review.

Comment: why are u having `$nom` in single quotes but `$code` does not have em

Comment: Nearly perfect answer, mentioned everything, a little syntax error still there on the query. http://bobby-tables.com for more information about SQL injection.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Think I code is a number, it does not need to be "converted" as a string.

Comment: this will produce undefined index `$nom = $_GET["nom"];`

Comment: @kaldoran yhea m aware but u cn add a little addition about that in your answer

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thanks, I edit it in order to change $nom and adding your answer.

Comment: change `<td><a href='editar.php?id=".$row["code"]."&".$row["name"]."'>Editar</a></td></tr>;` to `"<td><a href='editar.php?id=".$row['code']."&name=".$row['name']."'>Editar</a></td></tr>"`